Finite number of cuttings along the median result in an isosceles triangle
This question is inspired from the below problem from the $44^{\text{th}}$ Tournament of Towns: Senior O-Level Fall paper.

Consider an acute non-isosceles triangle. In a single step it is allowed
to cut any one of available triangles into two triangles along its
median. Is it possible that after a finite number of cuttings all
triangles will be isosceles?


Instead of all triangles being isosceles, I was wondering if there is a method to get atleast one isosceles triangle after finite cuttings.
This is how I started:
Consider $\triangle ABC, BM = MC$. Note that we can interchange $B, C$. There are only three ways such that $\triangle ABM$ is isosceles.
Case 1:
$AM=BM=MC \implies \angle A =90^{\circ}$, and we have a contradiction, since to get $\angle A = 90^{\circ}$, we must have started with a right triangle or an isosceles triangle (the median had to have coincided with the altitude).
I was unable to make progress on the cases $AB = BM$ and $AB=AM$.
Can someone suggest away to proceed? Is such an algorithm (to get atleast one isosceles triangle) even possible?
